# Why isn't Opc.Ua.UserIdentity sending the password cleanly to the OPC server?

Tags: api, opc-ua

I have a problem with the UserIdentity(user, password) constructor. 
My password is 4 characters long. When the password arrives at the server it is 36 characters long. The first 4 characters are my password - the rest is random garbage.

The Opc.Ua.Client.dll & Opc.Ua.Core.dll have version 1.0.238.1.

What is causing this and what can I do to send the password correctly?

**UPDATE**

```
ApplicationConfiguration configuration = Helpers.CreateClientConfiguration();
X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = configuration.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate.Find();
configuration.CertificateValidator.CertificateValidation += new CertificateValidationEventHandler(CertificateValidator_CertificateValidation);
EndpointDescription endpointDescription = Helpers.CreateEndpointDescription(Url);
EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = EndpointConfiguration.Create(configuration);
endpointConfiguration.OperationTimeout = 300000;
endpointConfiguration.UseBinaryEncoding = true;
ConfiguredEndpoint endpoint = new ConfiguredEndpoint(null, endpointDescription, endpointConfiguration);
BindingFactory bindingFactory = BindingFactory.Create(configuration);

if (endpoint.UpdateBeforeConnect)
{
    endpoint.UpdateFromServer(bindingFactory); 
    endpointDescription = endpoint.Description;
    endpointConfiguration = endpoint.Configuration;
}

SessionChannel channel = SessionChannel.Create(
    configuration,
    endpointDescription,
    endpointConfiguration,
    bindingFactory,
    clientCertificate,
    null);

m_Session = new Session(channel, configuration, endpoint);
m_Session.ReturnDiagnostics = DiagnosticsMasks.All;

m_Session.KeepAlive += new KeepAliveEventHandler(Session_KeepAlive);
m_Session.Notification += new NotificationEventHandler(m_Session_Notification);

UserIdentity identity;
if (userName == null || userName.Length == 0)
{
    identity = new UserIdentity();
}
else
{
    identity = new UserIdentity(userName, password);
}

m_Session.Open("ATF UA client", identity);
log.Debug("Connect ok");
```

Answer (score 1):

The rest is not garbage at all. It shall be the same ServerNonce you sent to the OPC UA Client in the CreateSessionResponse.

According to OPC UA specification the UserIdentityToken encrypted format is :

- Length - Byte[4] => The length of your password
- TokenData - Byte[*] => Your password
- ServerNonce - Byte[*]

The password is 36 bytes long because OPC UA Server mainly use 32bytes ServerNonce and your password is 4 bytes long...

You should also verify that the ServerNonce sent with that UserIdentityToken is the same as the one you provide in your CreateSessionResponse.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using a C# API and I can only assume that the library handles the ServerNonce correctly. I have added a section of my code to the question.

Comment: If you are writing a Server you will need to verify that the client added the ServerNonce you provided in the CreateSessionResponse with the password. If your are writing a Client you have to append the ServerNonce returned by the Server with your password...

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at the code I posted? My guess is that there is no communication with the server until the last line so where do I get the ServerNonce from? Surely this should happen within the library. I got the DLLs as part of a package from Siemens and they seem to originate from the OPC foundation. I have searched but not found any documentation for these libs. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I took a look but do not really understand what it was supposed to do... If you receive a password and want to check it, it means that you are on the Server side and you got a ActivateSessionRequest. So it also means that previous to that you got a CreateSessionRequest and you respond with a CreateSessionResponse containing the ServerNonce. So just check that the data you receive with the password is the same than the Password+ServerNonce. If it is garbage data check that you sent a ServerNonce in the CreateSessionResponse

Comment: Do you have the OPC UA Specification ? http://www.opcfoundation.org/DownloadFile.aspx?CM=3&RI=416&CN=KEY&CI=290&CU=12 - Check 5.6.2 CreateSession, 5.6.3 ActivateSession and 7.35 UserIdentityToken parameter

Comment: This is client-side code. The example above originates from Siemens - although they left the `UserIdentity` object empty so there are no hints on how to set the password. To the best of my knowledge, `CreateSessionRequest` is not exposed by the library.

Comment: To come back to your question : What is causing this and what can I do to send the password correctly? It is a normal behaviour, garbage data shall be the serverNonce (so 32bytes) and your password is 4bytes so you got 36bytes. The password shall be correct on those 4bytes but maybe encrypted if you choose Security Mode Basic128RSA15